# Filtering arrays for non matching elements as a result

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-apps-script

I am trying to filter for matching elements between mother and child array which was collected from a sheet which has to be converted to string and trimed for any empty spaces, to make a third array with non matching elements from the mother array.

```
function getVehicles() { 


//motherArray = ["a","b","c","d","e"];
//childArray = ["a","c","e"];
//thirdArray = ["b","d"]

var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Main Responses");
var ds = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Drivers and Vehicls");
var ap = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Approval Page");
var hp = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("helpersheet");

var lr= 15;
var Vehicles = ds.getRange(2,5,vehicleslr-1).getValues();
    Vehicles = [].concat.apply([], Vehicles);
var availableDrivers=[];
var availableVehicles=[];
var assignedDriver= [];
var foundVehicles = [];

foundVehicles = ss.getRange(lr,22,1,8).getValues();
foundVehicles = [].concat.apply([], foundVehicles);

availableVehicles = Vehicles.filter(function(val) { return foundVehicles.indexOf(val) == -1;});

//The expected output is the third array(availableVehicles) in the code i tried.

}
```

Comment: And what's your issue exactly?

Comment: Probably your issue is that you are not comparing primitive values, but instead `Array`s of values. Read more about JavaScript equality and about flattening arrays. Consider also that array traversal is not necessarily the greatest if you need to search for values repeatedly (consider object property access instead).